# A question about basis of homogeneous polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Let $R:= \mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots x_n]$  be the ring of polynomials in $n$ variables over the field of complex numbers.

Let $R_d:=\{f \in R \, | \, f \, \, \, homogeneous \, \, of \, \, \, degree \, \, d\}$

then $R = \bigoplus_{d \in \mathbb{N}} R_d$.

I know that this basically means that every polynomial can be written as the sum of homogeneous polynomials.

So let's say we have $\mathbb{C}[x_1, x_2, x_3]_1$ then $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ forms a basis for any polynomial of degree $1$, i.e. any polynomial in
$3$ variables over the complex numbers can be written as $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = ax_1+bx_2+cx_3$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$.

Similarly, if I consider $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3]_3$ then the basis is given by all the possible monomials of degree $3$ like $(x_1^3,x_2^3,x_3^3, x_1x_2x_3,x_1x_2^2, x_1x_3^2, x_2x_1^2, x_2x_3^2, x_3x_1^2, x_3x_2^2)$

Then how to formally express that any $f \in R$ can be written as $f=$sum of homogeneous components?

Answer (score 1):

Well, its like $f=\sum_{d=0}^n f^{(d)}$, where $f^{(d)}$ is the linear combination of homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$.

Comment: thanks, what is $n$ in your answer? The number of variables? Or just the number of *terms* needed to express $f$?

Comment: No, $n$ is just the degree of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

The statement $R = \bigoplus_{d \in \mathbb{N}} R_d$ means precisely that every element $f$ of $R$ can we written *uniquely* as a sum of terms chosen respectively from $R_d$ for all $d\in\Bbb N$ (but of these terms all but a finite number must be zero in order for their sum to be defined in the first place). The term in $R_d$ is *by definition* the homogeneous component of $f$ in degree $d$.

If you really do not want to express the "uniquely" part, you could weaken the statement to $R = \sum_{d \in \mathbb{N}} R_d$ but then you cannot use this to define homogeneous components of $f$.